# Get IP address of VM in azure ARM template

Tags: azure, automation, cloud, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to do cluster installation through azure ARM template, which has master, slave nodes in it. So wondering if there is any way to get the IP address of the VM using VM's FQDN in ARM template.

Thanks

Comment: https://resources.azure.com - you should look at this site, it will give you a general idea how azure api is scturcured. It should be under /subscriptions/xxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/AzureRM/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/

Comment: You can only provision dynamic IP addresses through templates. While you may be able to get that address out as an output, it is likely to change in future. You are better using the FQDN (just assign a name to the interface, and use that)

Comment: Question was sounding something like "how to" and did not highlighting any issues faced. You should be giving the problem statement and resolutions you have tried.

Comment: 'You can only provision dynamic IP addresses through templates. ' - this is wrong

Answer (score 3):

Use this in the outputs and it should do the trick. Generally if you keep the outputs empty it should give you all the provisioning details.

```
"value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses',variables('publicIPAddressName'))).IpAddress]",
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -5):

To get the FQDN of a VM:

```
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName("mytestpc1")
```

The VM must be reachable for this command to work.

To get the Private IP Address of a VM, this code should work.

```
$vms = get-azurermvm
$nics = get-azurermnetworkinterface | where VirtualMachine -NE

foreach($nic in $nics)
{
    $vm = $vms | where-object -Property Id -EQ $nic.VirtualMachine.id
    $prv =  $nic.IpConfigurations | select-object -ExpandProperty PrivateIpAddress

    $myobj = "" | Select "VMname", "PrivateIp"
    $myobj.VMname = $($vm.Name)
    $myobj.PrivateIp = $prv

    $csvArray += $myobj
}
```

Modify code to suit your needs.

Comment: Nice way to troll ;) The person is asking about ARM Template

Comment: @4c74356b41 This is ARM code. All he has to do is copy and paste it into his template.

Comment: I don't think we are on the same page about what ARM template is.

Comment: This is absolutely not an ARM template, it isn't even working PowerShell code. ARM templates are JSON based.